# problem with Pycham when creating a new interpreter and installing packages

Tags: python, pycharm

when I intend to create a new interpreter I can't install packaging tools and the following error occurs.
I'm stuck for hours now
I'm running python 3.8 64bit

[executed command and occurred error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3CQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that pip didn't want to install in the C:\ drive , i honestly don't know why .
So I just changed the installation directory of python ( other than C:\ ) and everything is okay now.